# Result row : null from HibernateTemplate Find()

Tags: spring, hibernate

The following line is returning nulls:

```
List accountList = hibernateTemplate.find("from Accounts a where a.userId=?",userId);
```

I am getting following information in the Console:

> 2013-04-03 21:09:48 DEBUG Loader:1197 - result row: null
>
> 2013-04-03 21:09:48 DEBUG Loader:1197 - result row: null

Here is my Entity class:

```
@Repository
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNTS")
public class Accounts {

    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_ID")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int accountId;
    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_NUMBER")
    private String accountNumber;
    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_TYPE_CODE")
    private String accountTypeCode;
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private String userId;
    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_NAME")
    private String accountName;
    @Column(name="DATE_OPENED")
    private Date dateOpened;
    @Column(name="DATE_CLOSED")
    private Date dateClosed;
    @Column(name="CURRENT_BALANCE")
    private double currentBalance;
    @Column(name="OTHER_ACCOUNT_DETAILS")
    private String otherAccountDetails;
    @Column(name="ADD_TS")
    private Date addTimestamp;
    @Column(name="ADD_USR")
    private String addUser;
    @Column(name="UPDT_TS")
    private Date updateTimestamp;
    @Column(name="UPDT_USR")
    private String updateUser;
    
    @ManyToOne
    
    private Customer customer;
```

Can anyone please help me with this? I would really appreciate it.

---

Here is the query that Hibernate generated

Hibernate: select accounts0_.ACCOUNT_ID as ACCOUNT1_23_, accounts0_.ACCOUNT_NAME as ACCOUNT2_23_, accounts0_.ACCOUNT_NUMBER as ACCOUNT3_23_, accounts0_.ACCOUNT_TYPE_CODE as ACCOUNT4_23_, accounts0_.ADD_TS as ADD5_23_, accounts0_.ADD_USR as ADD6_23_, accounts0_.CURRENT_BALANCE as CURRENT7_23_, accounts0_.customer_CUSTOMER_ID as customer14_23_, accounts0_.DATE_CLOSED as DATE8_23_, accounts0_.DATE_OPENED as DATE9_23_, accounts0_.OTHER_ACCOUNT_DETAILS as OTHER10_23_, accounts0_.UPDT_TS as UPDT11_23_, accounts0_.UPDT_USR as UPDT12_23_, accounts0_.USER_ID as USER13_23_ from ACCOUNTS accounts0_ where accounts0_.USER_ID=?

is there something wrong in query? or domain configuration?

Please help me.

Comment: What is the value of userId passed on hibernateTemplate.find()? Is userId really a string object? Does table ACCOUNTS have a column named USER_ID type varchar()?

Comment: Yori, Thank you for the reply. Yes, userId has a value and Accounts table has records for that particular id too. The strange thing is if I give following query I am getting values, but not when I want to select all the columns--   "from Accounts a where a.userId=?",userId       I am I missing any configuration in the Entity class?

Comment: How about if you set your "show_sql = true" and see what kind of SQL Hibernate is trying to execute? Also, try to execute the same query manually it might help to figure out the real problem. I do not see anything wrong in your code...

Comment: Yori, I have set the show_sql = true. I saw select query displaying in the console. that looked correct to me. Sorry, I don't have the application available now. I will post the generated query soon. I tried the query in database and I was getting 2 rows. Only here I am getting two nulls. This is so frustrating for me, I spent a lot of time on it.

Comment: Yori, Here is the query that Hibernate generated

Comment: @user2242869 did you get a solution for this yet? I am also facing this exact problem .

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little don't understand that why set the column of USER_ID String(varchar) type, but about your situation, you can write like this:

```
hibernateTemplate.find("from Accounts a where a.userId='" + userId + "'");
```

it'll work well, maybe help you:)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. USER_ID is actually not a primary key, may be I should change the name to more appropriate one. I will try the your query and see.